# Accessing profile data from teamcenter 13 3 user in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, teamcenter

I'm trying to return profile data from the the currently logged in user in teamcenter 13 3 using java 11.0.17 and Eclipse 2013 3. I've tried the method submitted a while ago (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21730281/14287068) but I've got problems with imports because either *com.teamcenter.rac.aif.AIFUtilit* and *com.teamcenter.rac.aif.AbstractAIFSessio* does not exist and I cannot use them.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this or provide some documentation because Siemens is not really helping.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same code in a dummy project and see that it alteast compiles without any issue. Of course, I did not run this.

[image: Eclipse build - Simple Project]

Hope this helps you!.